# Bootstrap active class gets applied on a disabled button in IE

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have two buttons of the form

```
<div id="btnGroup" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button id="button1" type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="button" data-bind="text: 'Button1', css: {active: isButton1Active}, click: button1Click"></button>
    <button id="button2" type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="button" data-bind="text: 'Button2', css: {active: isButton2Active}, click: button2Click"></button>
</div>
```

Both buttons on click display some list and the active class of bootstrap gets applied to that button. I have a scenario that if the list which appears on click of button1 is null, then that button should be disabled. button2 can never be disabled. This has been implemented in the javascript. This scenario works fine in chrome, that is, if button1 is disabled (the active class is applied to button2) and the user clicks on button1, the active class remains applied to button2 and it remains in focus. However, in IE(11), if button1 is disabled (the active class remains applied to button2), and when the user now clicks on button1, the active class gets applied to that and the focus is lost from button2(Yes, I am saying button1 is still disabled and the active class gets applied to that). I am gonna go out on a limb here and say the js logic is fine since it is working fine in chrome, but not in IE. Any suggestions about this?

Comment: Would really help if you provided a fiddle that showcases what you mean exactly. General thought: I don't see you actually disabling your buttons (no `enable`/`disable` binds). Note that the clicking a button will therefore be able to move focus to the buttons which might trigger browser specific styling.

Comment: How are you disabling the button? By applying a disabled class? If you are, then make sure to add disabled attribute also like `disabled=disabled`.